# C# creating multiple rectangles using for loop

Tags: c#, loops

Hey just wondering how I  can draw multiple rectangle objects in C# but have there yPosition updated say 10 pixels each time, so each new rectangle will be drawn 10px on top of the previous.

Here is the rectangle I am trying to work with

```
Rectangle hozBarRect = new Rectangle(xPos_ + VERT_BAR_WIDTH, yPos_, HOZ_BAR_WIDTH, HOZ_BAR_HEIGHT);
```

So this rectangle needs to be drawn around 6 times with a new yPosition each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (int shift = 0; shift < 6; shift++)
{
    Rectangle hozBarRect = new Rectangle(xPos_ + VERT_BAR_WIDTH, yPos_ + (10 * shift), HOZ_BAR_WIDTH, HOZ_BAR_HEIGHT);

    // Draw the rectangle here
}
```

You just keep adding the loop index * 10 to the yPos each time.